# Pushing files into private registry in Docker

Tags: docker, boot2docker, docker-registry

I have setup the private registry using `docker run -t -i -p 5000:5000 registry` and it is accessible from **192.168.59.103:5000** (I am using **boot2docker**). Now I have already pulled an image **tutum/tomcat** and when I try to push the image (`docker push 192.168.59.103:5000/tomcat`) into the registry after tagging it as **192.168.59.103:5000/tomcat** I face the following error as shown below --

```
FATA[0004] Error: v1 ping attempt failed with error: Get https://192.168.59.103:5000/v1/_ping: EOF. If this private regi
stry supports only HTTP or HTTPS with an unknown CA certificate, please add `--insecure-registry 192.168.59.103:5000` to
 the daemon's arguments. In the case of HTTPS, if you have access to the registry's CA certificate, no need for the flag
; simply place the CA certificate at /etc/docker/certs.d/192.168.59.103:5000/ca.crt
```

**FROM OTHER POSTS --**

I have read some some posts about this where they state that adding **DOCKER_OPTS** would solve the issue and that it should be added into **/etc/default/docker** but In my system **/etc/default** doesn't contain a **docker** folder as shown from the command `sudo ls /etc/default/` which provides the result as a sungle folder **aufs**.

Another post states that this can be thrawted by simply placing the certificate att **/etc/docker/certs.d/192.168.59.103:5000/ca.crt** but I am **not able to move into the docker directory even when I use sudo** as seen below -- for `cd /etc/docker`

`-sh: cd: can't cd to /etc/docker`

I have repeated the same process using the registry ip as 0.0.0.0:5000 inside docker (with the assumption the that `$boot2docker ip` should be used in the hosts machine and not within docker) -- But that still didn't fix the issue that I am facing.

Please do help me out to sort out this problem. I have added the system specification below --

System Specification:

```
Microsoft Windows 7 via. boot2docker (CLI version 1.5)
Client version: 1.5.0
Client API version: 1.17
Go version (client): go1.4.1
Git commit (client): a8a31ef
OS/Arch (client): linux/amd64
Server version: 1.5.0
Server API version: 1.17
Go version (server): go1.4.1
Git commit (server): a8a31ef
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To use the `--insecure-registry` option, add it to the file `/var/lib/boot2docker/profile` inside the boot2docker VM. You can get into the VM with `boot2docker ssh`. The file contents should look like:

```
EXTRA_ARGS="--insecure-registry REGISTRY_IP:PORT"
```

You will then need to restart boot2docker (e.g. `boot2docker restart`).

I have no idea why you can't edit `/etc/docker`. The following works for me:

```
docker@boot2docker:~$ sudo ls /etc/docker
key.json
```

Comment: I have added them but I get the same error as shown in the question

Comment: Sorry, I think those instructions were just for clients connecting to the daemon. I have no idea why you can't access `/etc/docker` as root; that doesn't make sense. It works for me is all I can say.

Comment: Does the --insecure-registry option work? If not, what is the error?

Comment: Are you saying you have set EXTRA_ARGS as I suggested and restarted boot2docker and it still says that?